# Creating new columns depending on other columns & rows and their integers

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

In my dataset I have columns and rows that consist of individual evaluations.
Each evaluation is scored between 0 and 5, or NA ( persons can't evaluate themselves ).

There are 4 persons in a group who have to evaluate the others depending on their input.

After each round each person can evaluate the other.

The **row** is what subject 1 *gave* his groupmembers ( eva2, eva3, eva4 ).

The **column** is what the subject *received* from his groupmembers.

For the purpose of a regression model, it seems worthwhile to know if a person shows more/less input could depending on how he/she is being evaluated. As in that the eva score given is included in the subjects row of variables, instead of a different row.

Thus I want the integer of **being punished by** to show in its row, thus a new column for the subject being evaluated with the integers of his/her members.

Also, we're making a dichotomous distinction based on X.
So if a person has `X == 1` we want a new column based on that X called `x_rec`, thus avoiding the `rec` vars.

There's one tricky addition to that, when `X == 1` this means that there are *two pairs of persons* **instead** of 4 individuals. I use `X == 1` as distinction, but we can also skip that and look at the NAs.

Because if there is a NA in eva1 **OR** eva2 **THEN** eva3 & eva4 are to be classified as the other pair (`x_rec`), and vice versa. This is also the reason why there is no `x_rec3`. Because within the pair, the other person also evaluates, but he/she will never get `x_rec` because he/she in the same pair as the evaluated person and thus will be classified as `rec`.

`subject group  round  X  eva1 eva2 eva3 eva4 rec1 rec2 rec3 x_rec1 x_rec2
 1       1      1      0   NA   2    1   1    1    0    2    NA     NA
 2       1      1      0   1   NA    2   1    2    2    2    NA     NA 
 3       1      1      0   0    2    NA  1    1    2    3    NA     NA 
 4       1      1      0   2    2    3   NA   1    1    1    NA     NA

 1       2      2      0   NA   2    2   1    2    NA   NA   3      6
 2       2      2      0   2    NA   2   1    2    NA   NA   2      3
 3       2      2      1   3    2    NA  1    2    NA   NA   2      2
 4       2      2      1   6    3    2   NA   1    NA   NA   1      1`

It sounds like I want to transpose, but I doubt it will be that easy. Unless we can transpose by `round`, that would make it easier (I think).

I have been working with ifelse statements, but it's quite tricky to get it done. For loops seem unnecessary, but I definitely can be wrong :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your starting data look like? Just the columns up to `eva4`?

Comment: @JonSpring. We are trying to predict future cooperative behavior depending on whether Ss cooperated in the previous round or didn't. The group can punish if someone didn't
`[1] "UniqueSS"            "subject"             "group"               "part"               
 [5] "round"               "treatment"           "contribution"        "contribution_next"  
 [9] "freeriding"          "freeriding_next"     "eva1"                "eva2"               
[13] "eva3"                "eva4"                "contributionRC"      "freeridingRC"       
[17] "contribution_nextRC" "freeriding_nextRC"
`